# Qt; start an external application and record events(mouse, keyboard)

Tags: c++, qt, events, external

I have a Qt based application which is running on Windows platform.

I want to start my application externally with the help of some technology and record mouse movements, clicks, keyboard input on it. After I want to replay same events on it.

Is it possible? Which technology?(Qt,Scripting(Python etc.),...)  Where to start?

Comment: Do you want it to "spy" on (monitor) some other application, or to record events along with its own application functionality?

Comment: @wallyk I want to record external application events with host application and replay it on external application.

Comment: I would use a command line argument to either record or playback events, then override the event() method in QApplication, then you can  save keyboard/mouse events to disk. (And of course read them back and send the events again).

Comment: See here: http://algoholic.eu/recording-and-replaying-qt-input-events/